# Length limit of default annotation title and subtitle on MKMapView

Tags: iphone, nsstring, annotations, mkmapview

Trying to figure out if there is a hard limit to the number of characters you can display in the standard annotation view for a MKMapView. I dont want to customize this view, and I also dont want the ellipses (...) to show up in my title and subtitle.

What is the limit to the length of a string for both the title and subtitle?

or, if there is no 'hard' limit,

How can I calculate whether or not my string will be post-pended with an ellipses (...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think following screenshot demonstrates best how much space there is on the mapview:

[image]

It seems like the resolution **width** is what limits you there.

Title: **32 Characters***
Subtitle: **48 Characters***
** Before the three dots show up.*

(I have to admit that I created a small helper `<MKAnnotation>` to accomplish this. That might be why there are no ellipses covering up the dots).

HTH